# Can't generate action listener in IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I'm trying to generate an action listener on the GUI form with IntelliJ IDEA, but there is one window that doesn't appear for me.

I've tried to reinstall the app but it doesn't work. This is the window that doesn't appear. I took this screenshot from a YouTube video.

[image]

Comment: Your question needs a lot more contextual information including your current code, where you're trying to add this method, just everything. Having said that, I urge you not to rely on YouTube videos to learn programming as their quality is usually terrible, and this often leads to much frustration.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The issue description is enough to understand the problem and find the known bug in IntelliJ IDEA: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-326683/Write-access-is-allowed-inside-write-action-only-at-com.intellij.uiDesigner.actions.CreateListenerAction.

Comment: I just want to point out that the OP never mentions what version of IntelliJ they are using, so now we're making assumptions. I also don't think posting on SO should be the first thing people do - again, no evidence to contrary, but if you found it easy to find the bug report, it raises questions about the effort that the OP went to to find an answer to their problem. So, yes, I agree with hovercraft, there is a lot of details missing - just saying

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, it's my first post. I'll keep it on mind the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-326683/Write-access-is-allowed-inside-write-action-only-at-com.intellij.uiDesigner.actions.CreateListenerAction) in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2 release.

As a workaround, please use the [previous IDE version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html) (2023.1.5) until this issue is resolved.

Comment: Just found this thread while I was searching about this issue. In version 2023.2.2 this bug was resolved.